# Why Alarm Manager Not Execute task at Midnight even the code was right?

Tags: android, alarmmanager

Scenario :

My task will executed every midnight using `AlarmManager`, let's say at `00:00:00` and should be repeated everyday

i use the following code :

```
Calendar setCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
setCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
setCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,0);
setCalendar.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);

PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, setCalendar.getTimeInMillis(), 1000 * 60 *60 *24, pi);
```

I also did this `alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, setCalendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);` but the result still same (not execute every midnight)

The receiver :

```
public static class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       //execute my task
    }
}
```

Android Manifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>    
<receiver android:name="com.projectx.activity.MainActivity$AlarmReceiver"/>
```

**The code above didn't do anything even midnight has passed. Is there any wrong with my code? please help.**

And also sometimes the alarm executed every several second after i set the alarm (not only at midnight)

I have no idea, what causes it.

Comment: broadcast called or other task not working?

Comment: @Divyesh : broadcast not called, sir

Comment: have you put alarm permission in menifest?

Comment: yes, i have put the alarm permission. i have posted it now

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, TestNotifyService.class);
            PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent1, 0);
long _Nalarm;
            Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
            Calendar wakeupcall = Calendar.getInstance();
            wakeupcall.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
            wakeupcall.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 21);
            wakeupcall.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);

            if (wakeupcall.getTimeInMillis() <= now.getTimeInMillis())
                _Nalarm=wakeupcall.getTimeInMillis() + (AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY+1);
            else
                _Nalarm=wakeupcall.getTimeInMillis();



           alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, _Nalarm,AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent);
        }
```

Comment: there is no warning i got, just not execute the broadcast, sir.

Comment: Put log inside of brodcast and check. Also post your menifest file

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code

```
Calendar setCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    setCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    setCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,0);
    setCalendar.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);
    setCalendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);

    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, setCalendar.getTimeInMillis(), 1000 * 60 *60 *24 , pi);
```

And the receiver:

```
public static class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //execute my task
        Toast.makeText(context, " hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Let me know if any issues.

Comment: i was checking the time for now....made hour min and date to zero u can check..Let me know if any issues

Comment: ok sir, i have to wait until midnight. maybe tomorrow i will notif you what the result

Comment: i have try another time (not 00:00:00, but 20:00:00), but the alarm still didn't execute the broadcast. Maybe it works when midnight has passed.